# Highlight Rows Based on Count of Rows and Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, count

I have a sheet that lists people with various start dates for vacations.

The sheet is updated constantly and has thousands of employees on it.

I have to go through the list and highlight every person that has three or more rows for their ID/name, that can be updated at any moment.

I know how to highlight the rows and I think I have a good approach. I was thinking a loop and count, as I need to look at each ID, count how many rows, highlight if needed, and then move on to the next ID.

I do not know how to write the code for that. I thought I could use offset and logic.

Attached is a sample. You can see that any ID that has more than two rows has been highlighted.
[image]

How can I get started on the loop piece and the counting logic? Am I completely wrong in how to do this?

Here is some of the code I tried. I was told only anything beyond two rows is to be highlighted per ID. If that is too much I could highlight every row.

```vb
If WS.Cells(r + 1, nameCol) <> "" Then
    nextName = WS.Cells(r + 1, appIDCol)
Else
    nextName = "Exit"
End If 'Else do noting on this If

If strAppID <> previousName Then         
    previousName = strAppID
```

Comment: You can do this w/ conditional formatting - though it may bog down the sheet a little

Comment: It looks like you're sorting by date but looking at the IDs. Do you only want the IDs highlighted if they appear next to each other or anywhere on the sheet?

Comment: You want to highlight if >2 rows but only highlight two of those rows (eg. why are the first 2 rows not highlighted)?  Which of the rows should be highlighted?  If you have some code you've tried, it would be useful to include that here - posts with no code tend to get closed here.

Comment: @bigben, thanks, I tried conditional formatting but as you said, it slowed the sheet down a ton.  Also, they want this tied into another piece of code I have already written for them.

Comment: @Warcupine, thank you, good observation!  Yes, anywhere on the sheet, however, I am told that they will be normally looking at this sorted by ID, so they would usually be together.  In fact, I would probably tell them that might have to happen as I cannot even wrap my head around it looking through the whole sheet lol...unless you can?

Comment: A dictionary could store the ID as a key with the item being a count, that would require you to loop twice, unless you only want highlighting on the third + instances, but that shouldn't be a huge deal.

Comment: @TimWilliams, added in some of my code in original question.  Just did not want my inexperience to taint the waters.  You guys know way better than I.

Comment: @warcupine, I have used a dictionary once before but do not really know how to set them up.  If I recall, it makes a list and then goes back through and compares the list to each next ID, right?  That would work too.  This seems like such a simple thing, I just to not know how to make it count and then know to check the next ID and continue on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Highlight only the third+ instance of each ID using a dictionary:

```
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change as needed
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'to early bind, add in the reference
    With ws
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Using Column B since that is what we are looking at for the dictionary
        
        For i = 2 To lr
            If dict.exists(.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
                dict(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = dict(.Cells(i, 2).Value) + 1
                If dict(.Cells(i, 2).Value) > 2 Then
                    .Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)'Change this to Range() if you don't want the whole row highlighted
                End If
            Else
                dict(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```

If you want all instances of the ID to highlight if there are 3+ instances this should work:

```
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ws
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 2 To lr
            If dict.exists(.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
                dict(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = dict(.Cells(i, 2).Value) + 1
            Else
                dict(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = 1
            End If
        Next i
        
        For i = 2 To lr
            If dict(.Cells(i, 2).Value) > 2 Then
                .Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: Warcupine, thank you, this was perfect!!  I had to change the Set ws to 'Activesheet' as when I tried to use your code with a corrected sheet name (tried changing the sheet name to Sheet 1 too, to match your code) it would not run.  After I did that, it ran perfectly, this is great!  See, this is why I come here, I know you guys will know the answers!  I can get stuff started on my own and do simple stuff, but things like this I usually need that extra bit that you all can offer up.  Thanks again!  Marked as answer and upvoted, not sure how to give any more rep to people!